# display taxonomy acf field in loop

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields

In Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) I created an image field and added that to the categories of a custom post type so every category can have his own image. Then I created a loop that displays the categories of that custom post type. This works but I can't get the image that I uploaded in the ACF field to display.

The code for displaying the categories of the custom post type:

```
<?php $taxonomy = 'customposttype'; $terms = get_terms($taxonomy); if ( $terms && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ) : ?>
<?php foreach ( $terms as $term ) { ?>      

    <?php echo $term->name; ?>
    // display acf image

<?php } ?>  
<?php endif;?>
```

I tried to work with 'array_combine' but I couldn't get that to work.

Comment: so you are not getting the image of category ? Please give the slug of taxonomy.

Comment: @AkshayShah indeed! Slug is 'behandeling'. ACF field name is: 'category_afbeelding'

Comment: try with my code now

Comment: @AkshayShah it seems to break the code, i don't think get_image exists in ACF? And nowhere its referring to 'category_afbeelding'...

Comment: Please check my answer

Comment: @AkshayShah you are getting close because its now showing '31', which is the input name value of the image

Comment: I got you now. Check acf did you set the return value as an id ? Change it to url otherwise we need to do some more code here let me know what you prefer ?

Comment: I set the return value to URL but its still showing the ID.. (thank you so much for this man!)

Comment: Re save the category image once or should expand the code

Comment: no luck yet! :(

Comment: It still give you the id no issue i edit my code and make it compatible with id.

Comment: Yes, that works! :-D

Comment: @AkshayShah still a small bug, when it loads the first image it goes well but it doesnt load the next in the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code in the loop

```
$term_image = get_term_meta( $term->term_id , 'category_afbeelding', true);

$image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $term_image,’full’);
 if ( $image_attributes ) : 
  <img src="<?php echo $image_attributes[0]; ?>" width="<?php echo $image_attributes[1]; ?>" height="<?php echo $image_attributes[2]; ?>" />
endif;
```

Comment: This works, added 'full' to wp_get_attachment_image_src( $term_image, 'full'); to make it load the fullsize image and not the thumb

Comment: Pass full in the function of attachment please check code